# Command 'Flutter: New Project' resulted in an error (command 'flutter.createProject' not found) and i cant debug flutter project on VSCODE

Tags: flutter, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have a question. I am using vscode and yesterday VScode is broken and deleted and re-installed But when I debug my project in vscode, there is no response and the computer does not show any error. I couldn't understand where there was an error.I would be very happy if you could help. I cannot progress in the 
project, please help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8TNn.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it by doing:

- Uninstall VS Code dart and flutter extensions and close VS Code.
- After this go to: vscode\extensions and remove all the files.
- Run VS Code As Administrator.
- Open VS Code and install dart and flutter extensions.

The cause for me might be that when you uninstall an extension files aren't erased.

I hope I helped you

Comment: Thanks.  For me, it was sufficient to do the first step, followed by deleting only the `dart-code.dart-code-*` & `dart-code.flutter-*` folders under `.vscode\extensions`.  Then, after reinstalling the extensions everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Install 'Recommended' to the current extensions (shown at the bottom right when you launch VS ). This resolved mine.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall VS Code dart and flutter extensions and close VS Code,After this go to: vscode\resources\app\extensions and remove all the files,Run VS Code As Administrator,Open VS Code and install dart and flutter extensions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).